# Timer not working on real iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to use local notification but something is not working.

I have a class notification that handle all the code related to the notifications.
It's apparently working. What is not working is the way I try to trigger my notification.

When the user clicks on the home button, I call my notification class that starts a NSTimer. It repeats every second, and each 10 seconds I call a webservice.

Everything works great on my simulator, but it doesn't work on my real iPhone.

Here the code:

```
//as a class variable
let notif = Notification()

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

        notif.triggerTimer()

    }
```

The notification class

```
class Notification: NSObject, WsOrderStatusProtocol, WsPinRequestProtocol {

    var timer = NSTimer()
    var time = 0
    var sendNotification:Bool = true

    var wsos = WsOrderStatus()
    var wsoc = PinRequest()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.wsos.delegate = self
        self.wsoc.delegate = self
    }

    func triggerTimer() {
        print("log INFO : class Notification, methode : triggerTimer")

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"orderCoupon:", name: "actionOrderCouponPressed", object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"cancelTimer:", name: "actionCancelTimerPressed", object: nil)

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("launchNotification"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    func launchNotification() {
        print("log INFO : class Notification, methode : launchNotification")

        time += 1

        print("time \(time)")

        if time % 10 == 0 {
            print("modulo 10")
            wsos.getOrderStatus()
        }


    }    

}
```

In the simulator, I see the logs et the logs that counts to 10 etc, but with my real iphone, I only see the first log "print("log INFO : class Notification, methode : triggerTimer")" then nothing...

Do you know why ?

Comment: Once your app is in the background then your NSTimer will stop running.  Running on the simulator/debugger is different. You should read the available background modes in the iOS application development guide from apple

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-) I'll try another method to do what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paul says in his comment, your app only spends a very brief time in the background before being suspended. Suspended means that your code doesn't run at all any more, so timers stop.

The simulator doesn't always follow the same rules. When its behavior is different than that of a device then ignore it. It lies.

If you want to have more time to do work in the background, you can ask for it using the method `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`. Make that call in your `applicationDidEnterBackground` method.

From testing I've found that that gives you 3 minutes of extra time. After that your expiration handler block gets executed and then you get suspended.

Apple does not want your app running indefinitely from the background. It drains the battery.

I've found that it is possible to lie and tell the system that you are an app that plays sounds from the background, and write your expiration handler to play a short "sound of silence" and then ask for another background task using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`. However, doing that will get you rejected from the app store.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-) I'll try another method to do what i want